# Can I delete older Android SDK Build-tools packages?

Tags: android, sdk, build-tools

I have all the Android SDK Build-tools installed from revision 17 to 21.1.2. Am I allowed to just delete old packages without any problem?

[image]

Comment: I always delete the old build-tools each time a new one is available. Of course after that I have to configure the projects to use the new build tool.

Comment: How do you configure it?

Comment: If you use Eclipse, I think it automatically picks up the latest tools available. If you use Android Studio, in the build.gradle file, there is a line called buildToolsVersion which you can set the build tool version as the name indicates.

Comment: thanks, i will accept it if you write it as an aswer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can delete the old build tools and that is indeed what I do each time a newer version is available. I have not got any problems by doing that. Eclipse ADT can automatically pick the latest available version in your system to build your project. If you use Android Studio though, you need to specify the version of build tools in build.grade file.